# how to load next track on event listener?

Tags: html, audio, addeventlistener

How can I load a new audio player `<audio>` tag in html5 when the user hits space bar or the track ends?

```
          <audio controls>
            <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
          </audio>
```

Do I need to create an event listener on key 32 or when the track ends?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For load an play a new audio at the end you can try

```
 <audio id='myAudio'controls>
    <source id='mySource' src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
 </audio>


 $('#myAudio').on('ended', function() {
      $("#mySource").attr("src", Your_New_sourcel);
      var audio = $("#myAudio");      

      audio[0].pause();
      audio[0].load();
      audio[0].play();
 });
```